# why do i get query twice

Tags: php, regex, youtube

I'm trying to basically extract the ?v= (the query part) of the youtube.com url... it's to automatically embed the video when someone types in a youtube.com URI (i.e. someone will type in http://www.youtube.com/?v=xyz, this program *should* embed it into the page automatically).

Anyway when I run the following code, I get two QUERY(ies) for the first URI:

```
<?php
//REGEX CONTROLLER:

//embedding youtube:
function youtubeEmbedd($text)
{
    //scan text and find:
        //  http://www.youtube.com/
        //  www.youtube.com/

$youtube_pattern = "(http\:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/(watch)??\?v\=[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\&[a-z]\=[a-zA-Z0-9])*?)";      //  the pattern

    #"http://www.youtube.com/?v="

    echo "<hr/>";
    $links = preg_match_all($youtube_pattern, $text, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER);     // use preg_replace here

    if ($links)
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i != count($out); $i++) 
        {
            echo "<b><u> URL </b><br/></u> ";

            foreach ($out[$i] as $url)
            {
                // split url[QUERY] here and replaces it with embed code:
                $youtube = parse_url($url);
                echo "QUERY: " . $youtube["query"] . "<br/>";
                #$pos  = strpos($url, "?v=");
            }          
        }
    }    
    else
    {
        echo "no match";
    }
}

youtubeEmbedd("tthe quick gorw fox http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qm8PH4xAss&x=4dD&k=58J8 and http://www.youtube.com/?v=Dd3df4e ");

?>
```

Output is:

> `URL
>   QUERY: v=5qm8PH4xAss
>   QUERY:                      << WHY DOES THIS APPEAR????????????
>   URL
>   QUERY: v=Dd3df4e`

I would be greatful for any help.

Comment: I've rolled back your question to include the code, though this is a reasonably long snippet the etiquette here is to include the relevant segment -- you've done that, leave your code in the question.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression stores a result in `$out` like this:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qm8PH4xAss
            [1] => watch
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.youtube.com/?v=Dd3df4e
        )

)
```

Your regular expression has a subgroup for matching the text `watch`, and so this ends up as a result in the array.

Since you iterate through all results `$out[$i]` you're trying to run `parse_url` on the second result of the first match; this leads to an empty output.

To fix your issue, simple change your iteration to something like:

```
if($links){
    foreach($out as $result){
        $youtube = parse_url($result[0]);
        echo "<b><u> URL </b><br/></u> QUERY: " . $youtube["query"] . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: There are two URI in the string though, would this work with both?

Comment: @john This will give you both.

Comment: Yay, thank you,.. I did what you said, and, removed the for loop, then it worked perfectly.